# Aborting connection to base by timer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to abort connection to SQL-server if it lasts more than 5 second. It is occure if wrong connection data given to connect method. But standart SQL `Connection.Open()` method can't be broken througth some time. Are any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: So, you mean like if someone gives the wrong username or password and it's taking long to authenticate, you want to abort after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the timeout in your connection string saying `Connection Timeout=30`. See MSDN documentation on the same https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx